# Recoding multiple variables at the same time

Tags: python, spss

So I want to loop over 200 variables (they are not in order) and recode string answers into codes.
I have a codeframe list in excel with over 2000 different codes for each string.
So as they are not in order I would like to use python in SPSS to do that, but as i'm new to that i don't know how to write actual recode code.

```
begin program.
import spss 
for v in ['a','b','c']: #list of variables I want to loop over
 # MISSING RECODE part ("string1"=1) ("string2"=2) ("string3"=3) etc.... up to whatever number of codes I want   
end program.
```

Could you please help with with missing part of code, I mean how the syntax should look like?

Thanks
M

Comment: Are you applying the same recoding scheme to each variable, or does each variable have its own scheme?

Comment: It will be the same recoding scheme for each mentioned variable

Comment: You need to provide more information than this.  What have you tried?  You should take a shot at this yourself so you can share code with us showing what you're trying, or you should at least ask more specific questions about the use of SPSS.  Please read [Can someone help me?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @eli-k's answer points out, you don't need to loop or do anything in Python in order to apply the same recoding scheme to multiple variables.  Vanilla SPSS syntax handles that quite well.  Having more than 2000 string-to-code pairings, however, can be problematic.  (Sometime I have trouble de-bugging RECODE syntax with only 20 pairings.)

The solution to this is to use the [AUTORECODE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLVMB_25.0.0/statistics_reference_project_ddita/spss/base/syn_autorecode_overview.html) facility together with its [APPLY TEMPLATE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLVMB_25.0.0/statistics_reference_project_ddita/spss/base/syn_autorecode_apply_template.html#syn_autorecode_apply_template) option:

```
AUTORECODE var1 var2 var3 
  /INTO nvar1 nvar2 nvar3 
  /APPLY TEMPLATE = 'my_template.sat'
```

The .sat files used by SPSS as templates are simply a special case of .sav files with a different extension.  They have exactly two variables:  a string called "Source_" and a numeric variable called "Target_" (note the capitalization and trailing underscores).  So long as you use those variable names, you can create your own template by importing your string-to-code mappings from Excel into SPSS, then saving as a .sat file.

One key thing to note about using AUTORECODE:  any strings found in the data that aren't in the Source_ column will be automatically assigned new codes.

Comment: Hi, thanks both, Kevin, but are you using this list of strings/codes in excel just changing file extension from xlsx to sat?. I tried to automate this but it doesnt work (kind of) https://ufile.io/csrzx here I uploaded a 3 excel files, sps with syntax , and i'm trying to save sat file and apply for every file, but when I'm trying to apply and save sat for file_part3 its making duplicates of my strings by adding space to it and giving it other codes

Comment: My point is, in my link above, there are 3 excel files with list of fruits, in first file im doing autorecode and just saving template, then on the second file I'm applying saved template + saving template again under the same name - until that moment it works, but then applying template on the 3rd file and saving template again it doesnt work like before, it giving random codes and in the .sat file I have duplicated fruits with white spaces.

Comment: I suggest you use `/APPLY TEMPLATE = 'my_template.sat' ` once with a few values, then open 'my_template.sat' to see how it is built and see if you can get the data in your excel file to fit into it. If you can't manage this way, I suggest you start  a new question for automating the task of getting values from an excel file into a recode command - we'll probably be able to help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

In SPSS syntax you can use the same recoding pattern for a bunch of variables at a time without looping at all, for example:

```
recode var1 var2 var3 ("apple"=1)("orange"=2)("banana"=3) into Nvar1 Nvar2 Nvar3.
```

Recoding into new variables is necessary if you want to recode from strings to numbers. 
Alternatively, if you do not want new variables, you could do this:

```
recode var1 var2 var3 ("apple"="1")("orange"="2")("banana"="3").
alter type var1 var2 var3 (f6.2).
```